# Installing Java Desktop Application on Windows 7 O.S

Tags: java, windows, derby

I have a java desktop application connected to a derby database 
the derby database has some dummy data for trial purposes.
The application is packaged together with the database(as embedded derby database).
When the application is installed on the desktop of my Windows 7 OS , I am able to 
access the dummy data as expected. However, when the application is installed in the program file folder, I am not able to access the database as well as the data in the database.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: _"I java a java desktop application"_ ...what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Program Files" folder is not writeable for a standard user (and for a good reason). Do not store any userdata there.

You need to put the database files into a different folder. This is what e.g. `%APPDATA%` is intended to be in Windows.

You can obtain the value of the `%APPDATA%` environment variable using the [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) method.

From within Java you can also put it into a sub-directory the `user.home` directory using `System.getProperty("user.home")`